How to write a custom script to migrate Magento 2 website products URL's target path to another site?
When attempting to redirect the target path of a URL to another site, it is not functioning correctly. Is there a script or method to transfer the URL target path to another website?
We attempted manual migration, but it would take too long. Therefore, we attempted bulk product migration using the CSV Export/Import method. However, we are still facing issues and are now looking for a script to easily generate the URLs.

Test this script in staging site
<?php
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Get URL rewrite resource model
$urlRewriteResource = $objectManager->get(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewrite::class);
$urlRewriteFactory = $objectManager->get(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory::class);

// Load product URLs from source site
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$products = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
    $sourceUrl = 'https://source-site.com/' . $urlKey;

    // Define target URL
    $targetUrl = 'https://target-site.com/' . $urlKey;

    // Create a redirect for each URL
    $urlRewrite = $urlRewriteFactory->create();
    $urlRewrite->setRequestPath($urlKey);
    $urlRewrite->setTargetPath($targetUrl);
    $urlRewrite->setRedirectType(301); // Permanent redirect
    $urlRewrite->setIsAutogenerated(1); // Indicate this is autogenerated

    try {
        $urlRewriteResource->save($urlRewrite);
        echo "Redirect created from $sourceUrl to $targetUrl\n";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error creating redirect for $sourceUrl: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}

